# Are classic and dynamic decorators limited to only the way they are applied or extend to functionality differences as well?

Tags: python, design-patterns, python-decorators

I am pretty new here and have been reading about Python Decorators and came across 2 types of decorator patterns.

1. Classic Decorators
2. Dynamic Decorators

What I understood as the difference between the two is, Classic decorators do not allow access to underlying object attributes. Now while the text part is understood, I wrote a code to see it for myself and I am unable to determine the category of decorator used in the example.

As for me, from my experiments and trials, I can change the attributes and see them reflected as well.

Code that I wrote to demonstrate this, is as below.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
import random
import string
import time

def timeit(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        stop = time.time()
        print(f'>>> Total time taken : {int((stop-start)*1000)}ms')
        return ret
    return wrapper

def generate_id(classname):
        return classname.upper() + "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=12))

@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    email: str
    address: str
    age: int
    id: str = field(init=False) #, default_factory=generate_id)
    _search_string: str = field(init=False, repr=False)

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        print(f'{type(self).__name__}')
        self.id = generate_id(classname=f'{type(self).__name__}')
        self._search_string = f'{self.name} {self.address}'
        time.sleep(1)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        print(f'{type(self).__name__}')
        return f'{self.name} lives in {self.address}'

@timeit
def main() -> None:
    person = Person(name="Amitabh", email="amitabh@ainebula.in", address="India", age=31)
    print(person)
    print(repr(person))
    person.address = "Bangalore, India"
    print("After change")
    print(person)
    print(repr(person))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I execute the program, the output of this program is as below. As you can see that when I changed the attribute, the change reflect well. What is the key point I am missing here? Any pointers?

```
Person
Person
Amitabh lives in India
Person(name='Amitabh', email='amitabh@ainebula.in', address='India', age=31, id='PERSONDUQLSUAGCJJJ')
After change
Person
Amitabh lives in Bangalore, India
Person(name='Amitabh', email='amitabh@ainebula.in', address='Bangalore, India', age=31, id='PERSONDUQLSUAGCJJJ')
>>> Total time taken : 1004ms
```

If anyone of you need more details on the question, kindly comment and I shall provide more info. As on now, this is the best I could frame my question.

If this does not follow the Classic Decorator pattern, I want to know how and why.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "classic" and "dynamic" decorator distinction as you put it, and it would be incorrect to insist in this naming scheme, since it may create confusion where there should be none.

A decorator will simply return an object, that will take the place of the object it is decorating - if it is decorating a function, the object returned by the decorator will be referenced by the name after the `def` statement, and for classes, it references the name after the `class` statement.

In the majority of cases, the type returned by the decorator is the same as the decorated object - a decorated function will be replaced by another function object (or another callable wrapping the function), and a class will be replaced by a class.

In *both* cases the object returned by the decorator can be the same that was decorated. That does not make such a decorator a "classic" or "dynamic" or anything - it is just that, classes, for one side, are easier to be transformed by a decorator "in place": a typical class decorator will iterate the class attributes, and perform transforms on them, returning the same class.

On the other hand, a typical function decorator, like the `timeit` above, will want to run some code before and/or some other code after the original function call: it is unpractical to return the same function in these cases - the far easier thing to do is to return a function that will run the prefix code, call the function, and run the postfix function. The original function then will be referenced only by a nonlocal variable in the wrapper function that is returned.

But that is not fixed: the `.route` decorator for web frameworks as Flask, FastAPI, etc... just return the same function that was decorated - it is added to a table where it is bound to the assigned route, inside the framework code. And for classes as well, `@dataclass` will usually change a class in place - but if one uses the `slots=True` option, a new class, copying the methods and attributes of the original one, is created instead.

None of these behaviors have to do with  "being able to modify the original object" by changing attributes on the decorated object.
In your question you have both a class, one where it is usual to change the attributes directly, and a function, where it is rare to want to change the attributes - but your example does not even try to change the attributes on the decorated function, so I miss what point you were intending to demonstrate.

And even then, there are ways for a function decorator which returns a wrapper function to allow access to any function attributes - just use the [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) decorator on your wrapper function itself: among other things it will copy any custom attribute in the underlying function to the decorated one. (Attributes are copyed at decorating time, and changing them won't be reflected on the original object - but them, one will rarely need to ever refer to the original function again. If the need arises, `wraps` also creates a reference to then as the `__wrapped__` attribute in the decorated object.